# How to check solr index size per field

Tags: solr, solr4, datastax-enterprise

is there a way to check the solr index size per field?

We have a large index size of 170G and we want to figure out which field is filling up the index size.

Comment: You can get some info, not sure how granular, using Luke https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler

Comment: I tried Luke but it is not working with datastax search. It is throwing me error. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec with name 'dse460' does not exist.  You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.  The current classpath supports the following names: [Lucene50, Lucene40, Lucene41, Lucene42, Lucene45, Lucene46, Lucene49, Lucene410, SimpleText]

Comment: Iirc Luke is bundled with DSE. Are you trying to use your own?

Comment: Am trying to use Luke analyzer https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke

Comment: Like I said, Luke comes bundled with DSE. Just hit it on your browser: http://<HOST>:8983/solr/<KS>.<CF>/admin/luke?&numTerms=0

Answer (score 5):

#### Alter your schema.xml

Here's the tactics you can employ to minimize your index size:

**1) Turn off [Term Vector](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent)** information if you're not using highlighting or other functionality that relies on it:

• termVectors="false"

• termPositions="false"

• termOffsets="false"

**2) Turn on [omit norms](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml)** if you're not using Boosts:

• omitNorms="true"

**3) Only index fields you intend to search**. As you mentioned above, you don't have to index all your fields

From what I've seen term vectors and omit norms can be a substantial percentage of your index ~50%

#### Learn more about your indexes

You can also introspect your indexes using Luke. Luke is bundled in DSE so you can access it from a browser by hitting:

http://:8983/solr/./admin/luke?&numTerms=0

Comment: We are already using these options omitNorms="true" termVectors="false" termPositions="false" termOffsets="false". However we still experience large index sizes.

Comment: Yes, I can see the luke output from the url but it does not show me the index size per each field.

Comment: As far as I know, you'll have to run some tests by re-indexing with different schema.xml's and seeing the impact on the index size.

Answer (score 1):

As of Solr 8.2 there is a new tool for index analysis
for more information see
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13512

Comment: it isn't relevant for this question. DSE Search includes Solr 6.0...